# cycle in a product of directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Does anyone know how to prove that a Cartesian product of two directed graphs $G_1 \times G_2$ has a cycle (not necessarily a Hamiltonian cycle!) if and only if one of the graphs $G_1$ or $G_2$ has a cycle. Thanks a lot for any ideas.

Comment: Can you at least prove the easy direction? If one of the factors has a cycle, it’s very easy to find one in the product.

Comment: In a product of two graphs we can always find all of the edges and the connections between them of any of those two graphs, and if one of them has a cycle, it should be quite obvious that in particular we can find that cycle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G\times H$ has a cycle. without loss of generality assume there are vertices $(g_1,h_1)$ and $(g_2,h_2)$ with $g_1\neq g_2$ in that cycle.

Start moving through the cycle $(g_1,h_1),(g_2,h_2)\dots (g_n,h_n)$and write down in a sheet of paper the values of $g_i$ but only when $g_i\neq g_{i-1}$. Do this until a value of $g_i$ has appeared before. The vertices you wrote down form a cycle in $G$.

Conversely suppose $G$ or $H$ has a cycle, assume $G$ without loss of generality. Let the cycle be $g_1,g_2\dots ,g_n$. Pick $h$ an arbitrary vertex from $H$. Then $(g_1,h),(g_2,h),(g_3,h)\dots (g_n,h)$ is a cycle in $G\times H$